# Replace already drawn bitmap on SK Canvas at particular point

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, skiasharp, skia

I wanted to update the existing bitmap drawn >@particular coords> on SK Canvas, while calling InvalidateSurface am able to draw but the previous bitmap is not clearing. New Image is beneath the older one! **Canvas.Clear(0)** didn't clear all previous bitmaps.

Needed help in getting over this issue.

```cs
void OnCanvasViewPaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
{
    canvas.Clear(0) // Dont seems be clearing old Bitmaps
    if (condition)
    {
        using (Stream streami = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceID))
        {

            resourceBitmap = SKBitmap.Decode(streami);
        }

        canvas.DrawBitmap(resourceBitmap, listPoint);
    }
    else
    {
        using (Stream streami = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(secondID))
        {

            secondBitmap = SKBitmap.Decode(streami);
        }
        canvas.DrawBitmap(secondBitmap, listPoint); // Drawn beneath the older
    }
}
```

Now the **if condition** changed to true outside the code blocks with  new value again calling  canvasView.InvalidateSurface();
Doest not clear previous

Comment: Could you provide some code example?

Comment: you need to show us the code where you are adding the bitmaps to the canvas and drawing them

Comment: Updated my question, my problem is canvas.Clear() did not clear all bit maps. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: this logic works fine for me

Comment: Is there a way to remove or canvas.Undraw like methods to make sure I manually remove previous?

Comment: use the Clear() method.  If this isn't working then I suspect something else is going on in your code

Comment: Sure thing! Take care

Comment: @TechCruize So you have one solution about your problem?If yes, please give one reply about your solution.